# error in user registration form using php

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to do the following but i have this error

it doesn't store in the my DB

DB name = job , table login , attributes : loginId , loginname , loginpassword

```
  <html>
<head>
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ?>
    <?php
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '123456');
    echo "from DB";
    mysql_select_db('job', $link);
    ?>
    <?

    class user {

        private $userId;
        private $username;
        private $password;

        public function getUsername() {
            return $this->username;
        }

        public function setUsername($username) {
            $this->username = $username;
        }

        public function getUserId() {
            return $this->userId;
        }

        public function setUserId($userId) {
            $this->userId = $userId;
        }

        public function getPassword() {
            return $this->password;
        }

        public function setPassword($password) {
            $this->password = $password;
        }

        function __construct() {

        }

    }
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST" >
        username :<input type="text" size="30" name="username" >
        password: <input type="password" size="30" name="password">
        <input type="submit" value="singup!" name="submit" />
    </form>
    <?php

    function addNewuser($user, $link) {
        global $userModel;
        echo "$user->getUsername()";
        $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO login ('loginname','loginpassword') values('%s' ,'%s')",
                        $user->getUsername(),
                        $user->getPassword()
        );

        $generatedId = mysql_insert_id($link);
        mysql_query($query, $link);

        echo "AFTER ADD FUNCTION";


        $query2 = sprintf("SELECT loginname FROM login WHERE loginname='%s' AND loginpassword='%s'",
                        $user->getUsername(),
                        $user->getPassword());

        $result = mysql_query($query2, $link);
        echo "$result";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo $row['loginname'];
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $user = New User();
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $user->setUsername($username);
        $user->setPassword($password);

        addNewuser($user, $link);
        echo "add done ! ";



        mysql_close($link);
    }
    ?>

</body>
```

Comment: you should add an `echo mysql_error();` directly after the insert attempt, so you can find out the real error.

Comment: tell me you dont really have a class definition in the middle of HTML????

Comment: also you can't get a generated id before actually inserting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your problem, which is

```
DB name = job , table login , attributes : loginId , loginname , loginpassword
```

I think your code at this bit

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO login ('loginname','loginpassword') values('%s' ,'%s')",
                        $user->getUsername(),
                        $user->getPassword()
        );
```

is missing loginID attribute, you can change it to

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO login (loginId, loginname, loginpassword) values('','%s' ,'%s')",
                            $user->getUsername(),
                            $user->getPassword()
            );
```

It should work. And please remember to eliminate single quotes in your query string :)

Comment: you dont need loginID, especially if it might be an auto increment

Comment: why vote down when I tried to cover all the possibilities that could happen? even if it's an auto_increment field, the query still isn't wrong, it just shouldn't be added :) remember that sometimes people get crazy with a single basic problem that they can't even think of.

Answer (score 1):

Your insert query syntax is wrong. Should be:

```
    $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO login (loginname,loginpassword) values('%s' ,'%s')",
                    $user->getUsername(),
                    $user->getPassword()
    );
```

Also please read about SQL injection as your code is vulnerable.

Comment: whats wrong with what the OP had?

Comment: @Neal: using apostrophes for column names, you can use backticks or no chars but not apostrophes

Answer (score 0):

PHP is case sensitive.

Fix it to:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $user = new user();
    ...
```

Also make sure that PHP erros are on when you are checking the code, because your current implementation should have thrown an error at that line

Comment: it doesn't solve the problem :(

Comment: the output is in this way 
AFTER ADD FUNCTION  Resource id #3    add done !

Comment: lol, too happy to think which answer is correct

Comment: @TrisLe, definitely did not think mine was the true correct answer, but i guess it was..